# Modifying mouse/touchpad sensitivity

Tags: 11.04, mouse, laptop, touchpad

I would like to increase my mouse sensitivity. Going to system settings->mouse and adjusting the sensitivity doesn't seem to affect anything. In the previous version I modified it in the advanced system settings by manually inputting the threshold and acceleration but I can no longer find that menu.

Ideally I want to have a constant acceleration with high sensitivity, is this possible in Ubuntu? 
I have searched for hours and was unable to find any relevant answers. Almost everything I have come across mentions the xorg.conf which no longer exists.

Help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Try Pointing Devices

```
sudo apt-get install gpointing-device-settings
```

It contains a nice GUI for changing touchpad settings like sensitivity, min/max speeds and palm detection.

Comment: That didn't seem to make a difference for me.

Comment: In 16.04: "E: Package 'gpointing-device-settings' has no installation candidate"

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem until I found this nifty program called [configure-trackpoint](http://tpctl.sourceforge.net/configure-trackpoint.html). Download the file from sourceforge.  Open a terminal and type in:

```
sudo apt-get install sysfsutils
```

Then go back to the file you downloaded and install it.  After installing it, go to your terminal and type in:

```
sudo configure-trackpoint
```

a GUI should open up and you can use it to adjust your trackpoint settings.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Doesnt work for me. The program also seems very outdated.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste this into Terminal, then hit Enter:

```
xset m 50 1
```