# Tap-to-click not working in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: trackpad, tap-to-click

I edited Xorg.conf as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/257915/increase-pointer-speed-for-trackpad-in-ubuntu-12-04) to control the speed of pointer movement for Apple Magic Trackpad in 12.04.1 and it works.

But now the trackpad does not recognize tap-to-click. I read the man page for synaptics but since I am a noob could make much out of it.

Appreciate community help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change this line in your xorg.conf

```
Option         "TapButton1" "0"
```

into this:

```
Option         "TapButton1" "1"
```

TapButton(number) sets the mouse event to trigger when you tap your trackpad with (number)fingers. "0" means disabled, "1" means left-click, "2" means middle-click, "3" means right-click.

---

*example*

If you want a tap with 2 fingers to be registered as a right-click, set:

```
Option        "TapButton2" "3"
```

---

Alternatively you can delete all three "TapButton" lines from your xorg.conf and the tap-click behaviour should go back to the way it was before.

Answer (score 5):

First, i located mi synaptics.conf file with:

> locate synaptics.conf

Mi file was in:

> /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf

I edited my 50-synaptics.conf with:

> sudo vim /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf

Finally i changed my original file, from this:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "touchpad catchall"
        Driver "synaptics"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"`
```

to this:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "touchpad catchall"`
        Driver "synaptics"
        Option "TapButton1" "1"
        Option "TapButton2" "2"
        Option "TapButton3" "3"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
```

Comment: Should you do anything after these steps? reboot or source the edited file?

Comment: I did this, then rebooted, and it now works so that a tap registers as a left-click.  The right- and middle-click still does nothing, but that could be due to my particular touchpad.