# Disable three finger tap of Apple Trackpad in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: xorg, trackpad, tap-to-click

I have configured Apple trackpad on Ubuntu 12.04 in xorg.conf as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/263079/78079).

I have also added

```
"TapButton3" "0"
```

but it does not disable three finger tap.

**My Question**

How to disable three finger tap of trackpad in xorg.conf?

Comment: What does three finger tap currently do for you? Is it middle click, or is it a Unity gesture?

Comment: It is used to move the windows on the desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Run the following in a terminal

```
synclient ClickFinger3=0
synclient TapButton3=0
```

If this does the trick (or a variance of 0 , 1  , 2, 3 , ) you can add it to startup.

(note i do not have a macbook,but it works on my asus. Please let me know if this does nothing at all)

Comment: `synclient TapButton3=1` worked for me on my Macbook 6,1 using Ubuntu 12.04... Thanks! :D

Comment: Scratch that, I used the value 2 instead of 1 and it worked better

Comment: yep, set the value to 2 as per [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133207/how-can-i-disable-the-multitouch-gestures-in-ubuntu) .  Works for me on my 13" MacBook pro

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04, I only need to set TapButton3 to either 2 or 3, but not 0. Any reference about this value will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling unity gestures is much more difficult than editing the xorg config file. They are build into the unity package itself. It is possible to disable all gestures by follow this instructions on the post here:

https://askubuntu.com/a/205045/41562

The commands/files given may be slightly different depending on the current version number of Unity. This "fix" will not persist if unity is updated. You can disable updates for unity using the command below but you will not get bug and security fixes:

`echo "unity hold"|sudo dpkg --set-selections`

Comment: I will **not** like to disable upgrades to Unity, instead can I decrease the sensitivity of three finger touch.