# How to stop my trackpad from driving me crazy?

Tags: touchpad, asus, scrolling

Using Ubuntu 14.04, very frequently when I use two-finger scroll it switches between programs (alt+tab equivalent) and this is super annoying! How can I keep two-finger scroll but not have it switching programs/windows on me all the time??

(Further info: I am using an Asus x501a refurbished laptop with a large, button-less trackpad with the right and left click seamless but designated in the bottom ~1/2" of the pad area, pad size approx. 3x3", I have both tap-to-click and 2-finger scroll enabled, natural scrolling is disabled, medium pointer-speed and double-click)

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Ubuntu 14.10 on MacBookPro8,1, and I have had success with the synclient command (check the current settings with synclient -l).  For me, the following command disables 3-finger gestures

synclient TapButton3=1

Alternatively, you could try to adjust the sensitivity.  Here is the link that helped me
[Disable three finger tap of Apple Trackpad in Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/272280/disable-three-finger-tap-of-apple-trackpad-in-ubuntu-12-04/276310#276310)

and here is the link with info about each gesture

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch#Supported_Gestures