# Disable trackpad two fingers + double tap with third finger bringing up Alt-Tab menu

Tags: 14.04, trackpad

Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS on a Macbook Air. 
Using exactly two fingers on the trackpad, then double tapping with either third finger brings up the same menu as Alt-Tab does.

Is it possible to turn off this shortcut?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently I was triggering 3 finger tap.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch#Supported_Gestures

The solution as posted by [rupert here](https://askubuntu.com/a/276310/355456) was to run:

```
synclient ClickFinger3=0
synclient TapButton3=0
```

> If this does the trick (or a variance of 0 , 1 , 2, 3 , ) you can 
>   [add it to startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up).

Specifically for me (Macbook Air 3,1 or 3,2), the following worked:

```
synclient ClickFinger3=0
synclient TapButton3=1
```

Comment: On a Dell laptop (Dell 7490) I need to set `TapButton3` to 1 to disable the gesture.